# How many different signing certificate do I need to iphone/ipad dev

Tags: ios4, code-signing, provisioning, app-store-connect

Do I need a different signing certificate for each different appID? or do I just need different provisioning profiles?

If I have two apps: com.domain.app1 and com.domain.app2  do I just need to create  4 provision profiles?

1 - Dev Profile for com.domain.app1
1 - distribution profile for com.domain.app1

1 - Dev profile for com.domain.app2
1 - Distribution profile for com.domain.app2

Also do you know why my new AppId/Bundle ID does not show up in my iTunes Connect when I try to create a new APP?  Does this mean I need to create the distribution profile first?

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to create two provisioning profiles using the wildcard character (*):

**1) Your dev profile.**

com.domaindev.*

**2) Your release profile.**

com.domainrelease.*

When developing your apps, you can re-use the profiles for any number of different releases by replacing the wildcard with an app specific string. Ie -

com.domaindev.app1, com.domaindev.app2, com.domainrelease.app1, com.domainrelease.app2

I hope this helps!

Nick.